# If statement error in a basic info input

Tags: python

I am creating a simple Python program that asks for basic info about the user.

```
myAge= input() 
if myAge > 20:     
   print ('You must be old enough to party legally now.') 
else:     
   print ('Put that drink down!')
```

MY ERROR

> if myAge > 20: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As myAge has to be an integer, it's better to convert it as soon as the user enters it:

```
myAge= int(input())
...
if myAge > 20:
...
```

and so, to fail immediately if (s)he didn't enter a valid age.

You can also catch the error and ask again:

```
while True:
    try:
        myAge= int(input("Please enter your age: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Your age must be an integer")

if myAge > 20:     
  print ('You must be old enough to party legally now.') 
else:     
  print ('Put that drink down!')
```

Comment: Very cool addition, thanks! Now how do i look up what functions i can use and how they work. for example to look up what try: means or what break means etc..

Comment: The Python tutorial is a useful reference - https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html (and explain the very same example, in fact...). And you can still google whatever you need, you'll find lots of answers!

Answer (score 1):

The `input()` function returns a string as the value and you can't compare a string and an integer, in order to do that you need to perform something like the following in the if:

```
 myAge= input() 
if int(myAge) > 20:     
  print ('You must be old enough to party legally now.') 
else:     
  print ('Put that drink down!')
```

Comment: That will raise `ValueError` for anything a user inputs that cannot be casted to `int`...

Comment: yes @zwer, but I assume that this is just for some simple use, of course we could put that in a try block but it seems a simplistic example though.